# Arduino Servo MG90S not moving

Tags: arduino, servo

I'm new with arduino (nano).
I am having problems with Servo MG90S, I cant make it move.
Im doing the easiest test, Servo cables connected:

Brown -> gnd
Red -> 5v
Orange -> pin 3

my arduino code is:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;

const int servoPin = 3;

void setup()
{
  servo.attach(servoPin);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{ 
  servo.write(40);
  delay(2000);
  servo.write(-40);
  delay(2000);
}
```

As you see its a super simple example, but the result is the servo vibrating slightly.

Extra data: the servo start vibrating with the `servo.attach(servoPin);` it doesnt matters if I set the `servo.write(40);`